# Set of all real numbers in $[0,1]$ which have 5 infinitely often in decimal representation has lebesgue measure 1

Tags: analysis, measure-theory, ergodic-theory

I am self-studying introduction to ergodic theory and found this problem (application of Poincare recurrence theorem) which I couldn't do.

I need to show the set, $E = \{x \in [0,1]: \text{decimal  representation of $x$ has $5$ infinitely often}\}$, has measure 1. How can this be extended to show that almost all elements in $[0,1]$ contain the block (this sequence of numbers appear consecutively and in the same order) $123$ in decimal representation infinitely many times?

What I did:
I know, by Poincare recurrence theorem, for almost all elements in $[0.5,0.6)$ have 5 infinitely often in the decimal representation. I am not sure how the Poincare recurrence theorem can be used to extend this to the whole of $[0,1]$. Any hints would be helpful.

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_number Especially the part where it says : The concept of a normal number was introduced by Émile Borel (1909). Using the Borel–Cantelli lemma, he proved that almost all real numbers are normal, establishing the existence of normal numbers.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy This uses ergodicity, the question asks whether this can be done using only Poincare recurrence theorem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to show that almost all points ultimately fall in your interval $[0.5,0.6)$ when you shift the decimal representation. What are the points who do not fall in that interval? The ones with no 5 in the decimal expansion. Can you show that the set of these points is of zero Lebesgue measure?

Then a small computation is needed to conclude. Let $I = [0.5,0.6)$, $B$ the set of points in $I$ coming back infinitely many times in $I$ and $A$ the set of points entering $I$ at some point, $T$ the shift of the decimal point, aka multiplication by 10 mod 1. Then
$$
\mu(I \backslash B) = 0, \quad \mu(T^{-n}I \backslash B) = \mu(T^{-n}(I \backslash B)) = 0, \quad \mu(\cup T^{-n}I \backslash B) =0
$$
and you should be able to conclude.

Comment: Thank you!! I could finish the problem with your hints. Can one extend this idea for numbers containing a block (say, 123) in the decimal representation infinitely often ?

Comment: Yes, this is the same. Nothing special here about the interval $[.05, 0.6)$. Use $[0.123, 1.124)$ instead.

Comment: I think there is a small correction (rest of it is completely correct). I think it should be  $\mu(T^{-n}I \backslash B) \leq \mu(T^{-n}(I \backslash B)) = 0$, as $B^c \subset T^{-n}(B^c)$. We cannot conclude $B^c = T^{-n}(B^c)$. Can you clarify this ?

Comment: Yes you are correct. I was a bit hasty.